# Codename One uniqueId for each app installation

Tags: codenameone

Does Codename One (on its servers) assign an unique id to each app installation? If so, how can I get that id? Is it reliable? If it changes after each reinstallation of the app is not a problem, the important thing is that two app installations never have the same id.

I mean if it exists something like:
`String uniqueId = Display.getInstance().getProperty("unique_id", null);`

Thank you

Comment: We used to track devices for counting on the old app engine backend but no longer do that. So that number doesn't exist.